# Unexpected Unity container behaviour with named and unnamed registration for same type

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm using Unity version 2.1.505.2 and seeing unexpected behaviour when registering a `UnityContainer` with a default registration and a named registration (with `ParameterOverride`) for the same interface type.

If I call `container.Resolve<T>()` twice - once for the named registration and once for the default registration - I get the same instance back, whereas I'd expect different instances based on the two different registrations.

Here's a code example:

```
public interface ICage
{
    IAnimal Animal { get; }
}

public class Cage : ICage
{
    public IAnimal Animal { get; private set; }
    public Cage(IAnimal animal) { Animal = animal; }
}

public interface IAnimal
{
    string Species { get; }
}

public class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public string Species { get { return "Felis catus"; } }
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public string Species { get { return "Canis lupus"; } }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnityTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        // Default registrations for IAnimal and ICage
        container.RegisterType<IAnimal, Cat>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<ICage, Cage>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        // Named registration "cage2" for ICage mapping to Cage with constructor parameter override
        container.RegisterType<ICage>(
            "cage2",
            new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<Cage>(new ParameterOverride("animal", new Dog()))));

        // Resolve ICage using the named registraion "cage2"
        var cage2 = container.Resolve<ICage>("cage2");
        Assert.AreEqual("Canis lupus", cage2.Animal.Species); // Assert succeeds

        // Resolve ICage using the default registration ???
        var cage = container.Resolve<ICage>();
        Assert.AreEqual("Felis catus", cage.Animal.Species); // Assert fails (Actual:<Canis lupus>)
    }
}
```

The second assert in the test fails because `cage.Animal.Species` returns `"Canis lupus"`.

Am I missing something from my understanding here? How can I set things up so that the call to `container.Resolve<ICage>("cage2")` returns the `Cage` instance corresponding two the named registration, and the call to `container.Resolve<ICage>()` returns the instance corresponding to the default registration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent 2 days solving your problem, and I've got it!

Problem is in named registration "cage2".

When you call:

```
var cage2 = container.Resolve<ICage>("cage2");
```

you run:

```
new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<Cage>(new ParameterOverride("animal", new Dog()))));
```

Look at inner `c.Resolve<Cage>`, when it called unity created object `Cage` with `new Dog()` as IAnimal. But! Above, you registered type:

```
container.RegisterType<ICage, Cage>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

So! Inner `c.Resolve<Cage>` creates no-named registration for object `Cage` with `Dog`. And, as it registered as a ContainerControlled, it holds the value, and when you call:

```
var cage = container.Resolve<ICage>();
```

you get value, that has already been created!

Fixed solution:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnityTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        // Default registrations for IAnimal and ICage
        container.RegisterType<IAnimal, Cat>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<ICage, Cage>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        container.RegisterType<ICage>(
            "cage2",
            new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionFactory(c => new Cage(new Dog())));

        // Resolve ICage using the named registraion "cage2"
        var cage2 = container.Resolve<ICage>("cage2");
        Assert.AreEqual("Canis lupus", cage2.Animal.Species); // Assert succeeds
        // Resolve default
        var cage = container.Resolve<ICage>();
        Assert.AreEqual("Felis catus", cage.Animal.Species); // Assert succeeds
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for spending the time on this. If `Cage`'s constructor had a load of other parameters besides `animal`, would there be a straightforward way to get `container` to resolve these dependencies automatically, while overriding only the `animal` parameter to use `new Dog()`? If possible, I'd like to avoid having to explicitly resolve each of the constructor's parameters as in `c => new Cage(new Dog(), c.Resolve<IFoo>(), c.Resolve<IBar>(), ...)`

Comment: @MattBecker82 well, you can register another named object (like "cage3") with PerResolveLifetimeManager and resolve it in InjectionFactory like `new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<Cage>("cage3", new ParameterOverride("animal", new Dog()))));`